# como poner spoiler que para revelarse solicite una clave

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

este es mi codigo quiero que cualdo presione ver me solicite una clave

```
<div class="divspoiler">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="if (this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = ''; } else { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = 'none';}" >Mostrar / Ocultar &#9660;&#9650;</a>
```

Aquí el contenido que queremos ocultar

Comment: Lo que buscas hacer es tener un spoiler cifrado o algo así? En plan que si no tienes la clave para acceder al spoiler no puedas acceder

Comment: Eso mismo, quiro esconder mis links de proyectos pero para que los pueda ver otro visitante debe ingresar una clave. Algo asi

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo diría hacerlo con JQuery porque es mucho más simple ejecutar y crear el código. Pero como no se si estas acostumbrado al Jquery lo he hecho en javascript y en JQuery.

**Información**

En mi página de ejemplo voy a guardar las claves en un array de javascript. Aunque mi recomendación es utilizar AJAX, PHP y MySQL para guardar las claves y la información. Por lo que tendremos una variable algo como así `var claves=["pepito"]`

**Javascript**

Para este ejemplo tendré este html

```
<div onclick="esconder_ocultar(this)" spoiler_att="0">df</div>
<div class="spoiler_elem">asdfasd</div>
```

Con este javascript:

```
function esconder_ocultar(elem){
    var clave_id=elem.getAttribute("spoiler_att");
    var clave=prompt("Introduce la contraseña");
    if(claves[clave_id]==clave){
        alert("Contraseña aceptada");
        elem.parentElement.querySelectorAll("[spoiler_att]+.spoiler_elem")[0].style.display="block";
    }else{
        alert("Contraseña incorrecta");
        elem.parentElement.querySelectorAll("[spoiler_att]+.spoiler_elem")[0].style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Esto funcionará de tal manera que llamará a la variable `claves` y luego cojera el atributo `spoiler_att` que indicará en que indice esta la clave.

Luego ejecutará un `prompt()` que hará que salte una ventana donde tendrás que introducir la contraseña.

A continuación checkea si el valor de la clave y el introducido son iguales.

**Jquery**

> **NOTA:** El porque insisto en Jquery es porque es mucho más sencillo de utilizar ya que no requiere de un `onclick` o de excesivas lineas de código

Teniendo este html:

```
<div spoiler_att="0">df</div>
<div class="spoiler_elem">asdfasd</div>
```

Con este javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var claves=["pepito"];
    $("[spoiler_att]").click(function(){
        var clave=prompt("Introduce la contraseña");
        var clave_id=$(this).attr("spoiler_att");
        if(claves[clave_id]==clave){
            alert("contraseña aceptada");
            $(this).parent().find("[sspoiler_attr]+.spoiler_elem").show();
        }else{
            alert("Clave incorrecta");
            $(this).parent().find("[sspoiler_attr]+.spoiler_elem").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**RECOMENDACIONES**

Mi recomendación como he dicho antes es utilizar `AJAX`, `PHP` y `MYSQL` ya que si haces este tipo de código a un poco que sepas de html o de la herramienta de desarrollador de cada navegador (click derecho -> inspeccionar) **podrían saltarse tu contraseña**. Por lo que te recomiendo tener una tabla MYSQL con todos los datos: La clave y el texto (no importaría si lo guardas con las etiquetas html ya que el Jquery es bastante sencillo añadir elementos)